# Google Speech API: Confidence is 0.000000

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I'm using Google Cloud Speech API as shown [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/speech/caption/caption.go) with the Go API.

When I run the example (`./caption audio.raw`), I get correct speech recognition:
`"transcript:"how old is the Brooklyn Bridge"`.

However the `Confidence` attribute in the `SpeechRecognitionAlternative` instance is 0.000000 (empty). Is this a bug with Speech API? I'm using the audio file supplied in the example [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/speech/caption/audio.raw).

Comment: I learned recently from Google that only the top-1 of the alternatives gets a confidence score.  Does that top choice also have 0.0000 confidence?